# Multithreaded JMS code : CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE or transacted session

Tags: java, transactions, jms, messaging

Edited Question : I am working on a multithreaded JMS receiver and publisher code (stand alone multithreaded java application). MOM is MQSonic.
XML message is received from a Queue, stored procedures(takes 70 sec to execute) are called and response is send to Topic within 90 sec. 
I need to handle a condition when broker is down or application is on scheduled shutdown. i.e. a condition in which messages are received from Queue and are being processed in java, in the mean time both Queue and Topic will be down. Then to handle those messages which are not on queue and not send to topic but are in java memory, I have following options:

(1)  To create CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE session as :
connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE)
Here I will acknowledge message only after the successful completion of transactions(stored procedures)

(2)  To use transacted session i.e., connection.createSession(true, -1). In this approach because of some exception in transaction (stored procedure) the message is rolled back and Redelivered. They are rolled back again and again and continue until I kill the program.  Can I limit the number of redelivery of jms messages from queue?

Also in above two approached which one is better?

Comment: Wow, you really might want to consider editing this question to be more clear... or to at least use understandable grammar.  I see plenty of familiar concepts embedded in this text, but I still have no "big picture" idea of what you're asking.

Comment: If I understand correctly - the question is, how can you avoid having your publisher code endlessly attempt to re-deliver a message to a queue when the queue is unavailable?

Comment: Question is edited and sorry for any confusions.

Comment: Based on the edits, I deleted my response.  Crowne's answer about checking backout count of the message is what I'd normally suggest. In WMQ there's a queue configuration that does this for you and requires no code. I have no idea if Sonic has a similar feature.

Comment: Sonic does have this feature, it's a property of the connectionfactory. I have detailed it in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface `progress.message.jclient.ConnectionFactory` has a method `setMaxDeliveryCount(java.lang.Integer value)` where you can set the maximum number of times a message will be redelivered to your `MessageConsumer`. When this number of times is up, it will be moved to the `SonicMQ.deadMessage` queue.

You can check this in the book "Sonic MQ Application Programming Guide" on page 210 (in version 7.6).

As to your question about which is better... that depends on whether the stored procedure minds being executed multiple times. If that is a problem, you should use a transaction that spans the JMS queue and the database both (Sonic has support for XA transactions). If you don't mind executing multiple times, then I would go for not acknowledging the message and aborting the processing when you notice that the broker is down (when you attempt to acknowledge the message, most likely). This way, another processor is able to handle the message if the first one is unable to do so after a connection failure.

If the messages take variable time to process, you may also want to look at the `SINGLE_MESSAGE_ACKNOWLEDGE` mode of the Sonic JMS Session. Normally, calling `acknowledge()` on a message also acknowledges all messages that came before it. If you're processing them out of order, that's not what you want to happen. In single message acknowledge mode (which isn't in the JMS standard), `acknowledge()` only acknowledges the message on which it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Without know what messaging provider you are using, I don't know whether this will help you.

MQ Series messages have a backout counter, that can be enabled by configuring the harden backout counter option on the queue.
When I have previously had this problem , I do as follows:

```
// get/receive message from queue

if ( backout counter > n ) {
   move_message_to_app_dead_letter_queue();
   return;
}
process_message();
```

The MQ series header fields are accessible as JMS properties.

Using the above approach would also help if you can use XA transactions to rollback or commit the database and the queue manager simultaneously.
However XA transactions do incur a significant performance penalty and with stored proc's this probably isn't possible.

An alternative approach would be to write the message immediately to a message_table as a blob, and then commit the message from the queue.
Put a trigger on the message_table to invoke the stored proc, and then add the JMS response mechanism into the stored proc.

Comment: Thanks alot for first suggestion! Second alternate approach I tried but backend people have some problem(DB/application level) in triggers. So I am using transactions in java code only.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about communicating with a message queue/broker/server/etc that might be down, and how that interrupts the overall flow of the larger process you are trying to design, then you should probably look into a JMS queue that supports clustering of servers so you can still reliably produce/consume messages when individual servers in the cluster go down.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't 100% clear, but it seems the issue is that you're throwing an exception while processing a message when you really shouldn't be.

If there is an actual problem with the message, say the xml is malformed or it's invalid according to your data model, you do not want to roll back your transaction.  You might want to log the error, but you have successfully processed that message, it's just that "success" in this case means that you've identified the message as problematic.

On the other hand, if there is a problem in processing the message that is caused by something external to the message (e.g. the database is down, or the destination topic is unavailable) you probably do want to roll the transaction back, however you also want to make sure you stop consuming messages until the problem is resolved otherwise you'll end up with the scenario you've described where you continually process the same message over and over and fail every time you try to access whatever resource is currently unavailable.